# Console.log returns wrong answer

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, it's my first logical programming language.  For some reason no matter what my income and loanAmount is the else console.log is returned.  What can't I get the "Approved" message to show?

```
function LoanApp(personName, income, loanAmount){
    this.personName = personName;
    this.income = income;
    this.loanAmount = loanAmount;

    var bankBranch = "New York";
    var approvalStatus = "invalid";

    this.submit = function (income, loanAmount){
        if (income / loanAmount >= 2) {
            approvalStatus = "Approved";
            console.log("Congrats you're approved for " + this.loanAmount + ".")
        } else {
            approvalStatus = "On Review";
            console.log("Your application needs further review.")
        };
    };
};

var tony = new LoanApp("Tony"5000,1000);
tony.submit();  //returns else console.log but should be "Congrats"
```

Comment: shouldn't the call be `var tony = new LoanApp("Tony",5000,1000);`? you are missing a `,` before the 5000

Answer (score 3):

Your `submit` function is defined as `function (income, loanAmount)`. Since you don't pass anything to the function, both are set to undefined, and `undefined / undefined >= 2` evaluates to `false`.

All you have to do to fix this is:

1. Remove the parameters from the function declaration.
2. Replace all occurrences of `income` with `this.income` (and same with `loanAmount`) in the function, so it knows what scope to look for them in.

Comment: Thank you.  I see why I need that.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is append the keyword this to the variables in your if then statement that determines if the value is >= 2.  This will give the function access to the variables, otherwise it can't access them because they are out of the scope of the function.

Javascript: jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/zrkdyq9c/6/

```
function LoanApp(personName, income, loanAmount){
    this.personName = personName;
    this.income = income;
    this.loanAmount = loanAmount;

    var bankBranch = "New York";
    var approvalStatus = "invalid";

    this.submit = function (income, loanAmount){
        if ((this.income / this.loanAmount) >= 2) {  //<-----change that fixes code



            approvalStatus = "Approved";
            console.log("Congrats you're approved for " + this.loanAmount + ".")
        } else {


            approvalStatus = "On Review";
            console.log("Your application needs further review.")
        };
    };
};

var tony = new LoanApp("Tony",5000,1000);
tony.submit();  //returns else console.log but should be "Congrats"
```